# Plutus Playground Client cannot run

Tags: cardano, plutus

I am trying to run plutus-playground-client, but I get this error when I run `npm run start`

```
[nix-shell:~/dev/plutus/plutus-playground-client]$ npm run start

> plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start /Users/danicuki/dev/plutus/plutus-playground-client
> npm install && plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm run purs:compile && npm run webpack:server

npm WARN ajv-errors@1.0.1 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN monaco-emacs@0.2.2 requires a peer of monaco-editor@^0.14.0 || ^0.15.0 || ^0.16.0 || ^0.17.0 || ^0.18.0 || ^0.19.3 || ^0.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 No repository field.

audited 752 packages in 3.101s

42 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 5 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[Info] Running: (Nothing,PSGenerator {_outputDir = "generated"})

Successfully created your servant API purescript functions!
Please make sure you have purescript-servant-support version 5.0.0 or above installed:

  bower i --save purescript-servant-support

The following purescript packages are needed by the generated code:

  - plutus-playground-client
  - purescript-either
  - purescript-foreign-generic
  - purescript-maybe
  - purescript-ordered-collections
  - purescript-profunctor-lenses
  - web-common

Successfully created your PureScript modules!
plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: InterpreterError (CompilationErrors [CompilationError {filename = "\n/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-f7221c0023582e5f/Main.hs", row = 2, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not load module \8216Playground.Contract\8217","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216playground-common-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package playground-common\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","2 | import           Playground.Contract","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-f7221c0023582e5f/Main.hs", row = 3, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not load module \8216Plutus.Contract\8217","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-contract-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-contract\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","3 | import           Plutus.Contract","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-f7221c0023582e5f/Main.hs", row = 4, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not load module \8216PlutusTx.Prelude\8217","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-tx-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-tx\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-tx-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-tx\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","4 | import           PlutusTx.Prelude","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]}]))
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `npm install && plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm run purs:compile && npm run webpack:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/danicuki/.npm/_logs/2021-07-06T16_34_12_339Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve

Comment: Have you run `npm run start` in nix-shell..?

Comment: yes, I did. :-)

Comment: What's your operating system? If you're using Windows and WSL, make sure the plutus repo clone is located in the WSL filesystem.

Comment: this situation happens on MacOS