# Problem running Plutus Playground Client on MacOS

Tags: haskell, nix, cardano, plutus

I am encountering a problem when trying to run the Plutus Playground through Nix on MacOS.

I tried using the last available tag v2021-12-20, but I am getting the following error when I try to run the Plutus Playground Client in nix-shell:

```
nix-shell:~/cardano/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client]$ npm run start

> plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start /Users/matt/cardano/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client
> plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev

/nix/store/2nr8xfy3zqdgxfmxlc3r48gijfdwbnrf-plutus-playground-generate-purs/bin/plutus-playground-generate-purs: line 6: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/matt/.npm/_logs/2021-12-20T18_27_49_943Z-debug.log
```

It seems similar to [Plutus Playground Client cannot run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276780/plutus-playground-client-cannot-run/70426131?noredirect=1#comment124491877_70426131), but I couldn't find anything to help run it.

My Nix config:

```
uild-users-group = nixbld

substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=

sandbox = false

system = x86_64-darwin
extra-platforms = x86_64-darwin aarch64-darwin
```

I am running it on an M1 Mac.

Comment: I think you will have better luck asking your question on some Plutus or Cardano especific forum.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you should follow this guide for setting up your Plutus enviornment on an M1 chip https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Environment/Build/Mac_M1/